# Angular JS Check Box Based Calendar Events

Tags: angularjs

I am a JS Novice. I'm looking to take my code and convert this form to a "check box" type response. The end goal is to have the user check time slots (8:00-8:30) by simply clicking on the calendar.

I'd like to do this in a way that will dynamically create events when a particular time-slot is chosen. There is absolutely no need to have an event that spans larger than one particular 30 minute slot. Naming events is also not an issue.

```
<table class="calendar table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="14%">Sunday</th>
        <th width="14%">Monday</th>
        <th width="14%">Tuesday</th>
        <th width="14%">Wednesday</th>
        <th width="14%">Thursday</th>
        <th width="14%">Friday</th>
        <th width="14%">Saturday</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>08:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>09:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>09:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10:00</td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="6">

            <div class="row-fluid lecture" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Combinatorics</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Prof.
                        Someone</a></span> <span class="location">23/111</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid lecture" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Algebra 2</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Prof.
                        Else <span class="location">44/654</span>

            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid lecture" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Data Structures</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Prof.
                        If</a></span> <span class="location">54/222</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>
    <tr>
        <td>12:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>14:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid lecture" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Data Structures</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Prof.
                        Oak</a></span> <span class="location">33/111</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="6">

            <div class="row-fluid lecture" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Calculus 1</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Dr.
                        Ok</a></span> <span class="location">12/54</span>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>14:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>16:00</td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid practice" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Calculus 1</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Mrs.
                        Ak</a></span> <span class="location">54/125</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid lecture" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Combinatorics</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Ms.
                        Nice</a></span> <span class="location">99/411</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid practice" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Combinatorics</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Ms.
                        K</a></span> <span class="location">24/900</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class=" has-events" rowspan="4">

            <div class="row-fluid practice" style="width: 99%; height: 100%;">


                <span class="title">Data Structures</span> <span class="lecturer"><a>Mr.
                        Ben</a></span> <span class="location">54/214</span>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>16:30</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>18:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>18:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>19:00</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>19:30</td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

        <td class=" no-events" rowspan="1"></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understand the question, a possibility for what you want to do is to map grid cells to a data structure and use angular to set the status of those cells. That is, you store an object representing time slots in your controller / directive.

For instance, suppose that you want to store days as columns and times as rows. Cells represent timeslots, that can be "checked" or not. So a possibility is:

```
$scope.calendar = { 
  firstRow : { time: '8.00', cells: [ 
    { day: 'monday', event: 'Algebra', checked: false },
    { day: 'tuesday', event: '', checked: false }, 
    //... and so on until friday
  ]},
  secondRow: { time: '8.30', cells: [
    { day: 'monday', event: '', checked: false },
    //... and so on until friday
  ]},
  //... and so on until the last row, that represents 19.30 
}
```

Of course, you want to generate such a structure using loops, not by writing it by hand. The above is just for the sake of clarity.

At this point, in your table, you can exploit the `ng-repeat` attribute to generate checkable cells and `ng-class` to see if a cell has been checked or not.
i.e., for the '8.30' time you have:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{calendar.secondRow.time}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="cell in calendar.secondRow.cells" 
    ng-class="cell.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'"
    ng-click="cell.checked=!cell.checked">
      <input type="text" ng-model="cell.event">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Obviously you want to define the `checked` class in your style (and possibly `unchecked` aswell). For example add `td.checked { background-color: red; }` to your style.

Again, you can also avoid to manually declare a `<tr>` for each time slot (you can cycle through the properties of `$scope.calendar`), but I gave you the code above so that it is easier for you to understand what I mean :)

Take a look at this toy-example:

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller('CalendarCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.calendar = {
    firstSlot : {
      time : '8.00',
      cells : [
        { day: 'monday', event: 'algebra', checked: false},
        { day: 'tuesday', event: 'history', checked: false},
      ]
    },
    secondSlot : {
      time : '8.30',
      cells : [
        { day: 'monday', event: 'math', checked: false},
        { day: 'tuesday', event: 'chemistry', checked: false},
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td.checked {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>click on a cell!</p>
  
  <table ng-controller="CalendarCtrl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th><th>mon</th><th>tue</th>
      </tr>
      
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>{{calendar.firstSlot.time}}</td>
      
      <td ng-repeat="cell in calendar.firstSlot.cells" 
    ng-class="cell.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'"
    ng-click="cell.checked=!cell.checked">
      {{cell.event}}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{calendar.secondSlot.time}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="cell in calendar.secondSlot.cells" 
    ng-class="cell.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'"
    ng-click="cell.checked=!cell.checked">
      {{cell.event}}
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.